# TreePlot EdgeLabeling Style

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, bugs

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and persisting through 11.3 or later. Fixed in 13.1.0 or earlier.**

---

I am trying to control the style for edge labels in treeplot and have run into a problem.

Consider these two graphs:

```
edges1 = {{1 -> 2,"Test"}, 2 -> 3}
edges2 = {{1 -> 2,"Test"}, 2 -> 3, 1 -> 4}
```

If I plot the first then the labeled edge displays correctly:

```
TreePlot[edges1, BaseStyle-> 20]
```

[image]

But if I plot the second it slants the text:

```
TreePlot[edges2, BaseStyle-> 20]
```

[image]

Anyone have any insight how to stop the second behavior?

**Edit**

Here is a more complicated example showing how it slants the text in both directions and in different amounts (Note that in actuality my edges have different labels)

```
edges = {{1 -> 2, "Test"}, {1 -> 3, "Test"}, {2 -> 14, 
"Test"}, {3 -> 4, "Test"}, {4 -> 99, "Test"}, {3 -> 6, 
"Test"}, {6 -> 7, "Test"}, {6 -> 8, "Test"}, {7 -> 9, 
"Test"}, {8 -> 10, "Test"}, {8 -> 11, "Test"}, {10 -> 12, 
"Test"}, {11 -> 13, "Test"}};
edges[[All, 2]] = Map[Panel@Style[#, 12] &, edges[[All, 2]]];
TreePlot[edges, Top, 1, AspectRatio -> 1/3]
```

[image]

**Edit 2 **
Combining M.R.'s solution and LayerSizeFunction I can somewhat still control the aspect ratio, but Mr. Wizard's solution is much better

M.R. + LayerSizeFunction:

```
DeleteCases[TreePlot[edges, Top, 1, LayerSizeFunction -> (1/4 # &)], AspectRatio -> _]
```

[image]
Mr. Wizard:

```
edges3 = {{1 -> 2, "Test"}, {1 -> 3, "Test"}, {2 -> 14, 
"Test"}, {3 -> 4, "Test"}, {4 -> 99, "Test"}, {3 -> 6, 
"Test"}, {6 -> 7, "Test"}, {6 -> 8, "Test"}, {7 -> 9, 
"Test"}, {8 -> 10, "Test"}, {8 -> 11, "Test"}, {10 -> 12, 
"Test"}, {11 -> 13, "Test"}};
TreePlot[edges3, Top, 1, AspectRatio -> 1/3, EdgeRenderingFunction -> ({Line[#1], 
 If[#3 === None, {}, Text[Panel@Style[#3, 16], Mean@#1]]} &)]
```

[image]

Comment: I believe I found the source of the problem and I have provided a correction method in my revised answer.

Comment: I added the `bugs` tag to this; anyone who disagrees please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The labels are implemented in terms of [`Arrowheads`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrowheads.html) and [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) in a rather strange way.  One fix is to render the labels manually with a custom [`EdgeRenderingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeRenderingFunction.html):

```
TreePlot[edges2, BaseStyle -> 20,
 EdgeRenderingFunction ->
  ({Line[#1], If[#3 === None, {}, Text[Panel@#3, Mean@#1]]} &)
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Regarding the default rendering, an arrowhead normally points in the direction of the arrow and therefore the labels, implemented as Arrowheads, would also point in the direction of the line.  The fifth argument of `Inset` is used to compensate for this but the implementation is flawed.  You can see the default alignment with:

```
TreePlot[edges2, BaseStyle -> 20] /. 
 Inset[a_, b_, c_, d_, DIR_, opts__] :> Inset[a, b, c, d, opts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Solution

We can correct the fifth argument from `None` to `{None, None}` like this:

```
edges = {{1 -> 2, "Test"}, {1 -> 3, "Test"}, {2 -> 14, 
    "Test"}, {3 -> 4, "Test"}, {4 -> 99, "Test"}, {3 -> 6, 
    "Test"}, {6 -> 7, "Test"}, {6 -> 8, "Test"}, {7 -> 9, 
    "Test"}, {8 -> 10, "Test"}, {8 -> 11, "Test"}, {10 -> 12, 
    "Test"}, {11 -> 13, "Test"}};

edges[[All, 2]] = Map[Panel[Style[#, 12], FrameMargins -> 2] &, edges[[All, 2]]];

TreePlot[edges, Top, 1, AspectRatio -> 1/3] /. 
  Inset[a__, None, opts___] :> Inset[a, {None, None}, opts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great explanation of the behavior and perfect solution!

Comment: @David Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to me to be a bug with AspectRatio in the graphic boxes

```
TreePlot[edges2, AspectRatio -> 2]
```

works for this example, so try for your more complicated example (which you should post the code for) try

```
DeleteCases[TreePlot[edges3, EdgeLabeling -> True], AspectRatio -> _]
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work on more complicated graphs as it slants the font in both directions and by different amounts depending on the angle of the edge

Comment: That does work, but I also want to be able to control the aspect ratio of the plot

Answer (score 0):

The situation appears to have been resolved - see below

[image: screen1]
[image: screen2]