# How do I rotate the vertex labels within a LayeredGraphPlot

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

Is there any way to rotate the vertex labels within a LayerdGraphPlot by, say, 20 degrees without affecting the rest of the plot?

```
stuff = {};
AppendTo[stuff, "Product 1" -> "Process"];
AppendTo[stuff, "Product 2" -> "Process"];
AppendTo[stuff, "Process" -> "Result"];
plot = LayeredGraphPlot[stuff, VertexLabeling -> True, DirectedEdges -> True]
```

I wasn't able to find anything.  `Rotate[]` only affects the entire plot.  There is a `PlotStyle` attribute, but I can't think of any way to use that the effect the desired result.

Comment: `plot /. f_Framed :> Rotate[f, 20. Degree]`

Comment: Related: [(13541)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13541/121)

Comment: If you are using the newer `Graph` with `GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"` instead of the old `LayeredGraphPlot`, you can use `VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center, Rotate[#, Pi/2] &]` as a starting point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`VertexRenderingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VertexRenderingFunction) option:

```
LayeredGraphPlot[
    stuff,
    VertexRenderingFunction->({Text[Framed[#2,Background->White],#1,{0,0},{0,1}]}&)
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Also

```
LayeredGraphPlot[Rotate[#, 90 Degree] & /@ # & /@ stuff, 
 VertexLabeling -> True, DirectedEdges -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]